# Decimal values in AJAX URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get

I'm currently trying to pass values using an AJAX request to a server side end point. Everything works fine until I try to pass a decimal value in the url. I understand that the . character is a reserved character in the url and am wondering how I can pass a decimal value in my AJAX request.

My current endpoint is something like this; /domain/some-url/?value1=5&value2=2.3
The above url results in a 404.

If I change value2 to a whole number or a string it works file.  Example would be /domain/some-url/?value1=5&value2=2
I get a successful response from the above URL.

Is there a standard way of deal with this situation?

Comment: What code are you using to send your ajax request?

Comment: What is the error message you get when you include the dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the dot per se. Why would a dot be a reserved character in a URL? In that case you wouldn't be able to use `/img/someimg.jpg` etc. It must have something to do with the way your server handles the request.

To be sure, I have tested this using one of my own server side testscripts @[`http://testbed.nicon.nl/v8test/json.xjs?testone=0.234&test2=4.56`](http://testbed.nicon.nl/v8test/json.xjs?testone=0.234&test2=4.56). The script is found and working like it should, no problem with the decimals.

Answer (score 3):

No, `.` is not a reserved character in URLs – see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3 – so whether it's URL-encoded or not should make no difference.

It sounds to me like the problem is instead with the server-side script not accepting dots in that argument, but it's difficult to tell why without more details.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be in your server, `.` is not reserved. I actually **tried** to use encodeURI in my browser:

```
> encodeURI("/domain/some-url/?value1=5&value2=2.3")
"/domain/some-url/?value1=5&value2=2.3"
```

The result does not change. **Try it**.

Answer (score 0):

Please check **.htaccess** or **routing script** on your domain/server to allow . in params;

otherwise

> /domain/some-url/?value1=5&value2=2.3

is a correct way to pass decimal value in the url;

Answer (score -2):

try sending arguments as below in your ajax request;

```
data: { value1:5, value2: 2.3 }
```